# Checar se array contém caractere específico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array, array-push

Preciso checar se um array tem um caractere específico (esse: | ). Se conter, esse caractere deve ser eliminado e a próxima palavra que estaria após essa caractere (que na verdade é uma separação de itens) seria adicionada no próximo index. Ou seja, o array não pode ter em seu conteúdo o caractere citado acima. Se houver, eliminá-lo e adicionar no array a palavra que estaria após esse tal caractere.

A imagem em anexo reflete o problema.
Preciso resolver com javascript/jquery.[image: Exemplo do Array com o caractere específico onde preciso eliminá-lo e adicionar o item "Corte Masculino" no próximo index, que seria no caso desse exemplo: 6.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se quiser alterar apenas a array original sem criar uma nova, e ainda compatível com todos os navegadores, inclusive o IE 11 (a *arrow function* `item =>` no `forEach` não tem suporte no IE 11, sem tirar os méritos da resposta do *vnbrs*):

```js
var array = ["Escova|Corte Masculino", "Gel", "Cabelo|Corte Masculino", "Escova", "Gel", "Gel|Corte Masculino"];

for(var x=0; x<array.length; x++){
   var i = array[x];
   var idx = i.indexOf("|");
   if(~idx){
      array[x] = i.substr(idx+1);
      array.splice(x, 0, i.substr(0, idx));
   }
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Boa resposta. Estive pensando como os funcionalistas fazem. Acredito que um map inserindo arrays com arrays para itens múltiplos, seguidos de um flatten. Não sei.... 

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar um laço, combinado com o `Array.concat` e um `String.split` para separar os itens com o pipe.

```
const arrayOriginal = ["Tomate", "Abacaxi", "Carne|Fritas"];
let novoArray = [];

arrayOriginal.forEach(item => {
  novoArray = novoArray.concat(item.split("|"));
});
```

O resultado é

```
["Tomate", "Abacaxi", "Carne", "Fritas"]
```

Comment: Gostei do código, bem simples e enxuto, mas se houvesse um jeito de não ter que criar outra array, digo, somente alterando a original, seria perfect. Mas mesmo assim uma boa resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição ao meu aprendizado @Sam e @vnbrs!

Answer (score 2):

Fala Pessoal :)

Só adicionando aqui uma forma de fazer com o jquery, ela usa também expressão regular, mas pode ajudar bastante na tarefa de não criar uma nova Array 0/

```
var teste = ['Escova|Corte Masculino','Gel','Cabelo|Corte Masculino']; // Array com os dados
teste = teste.toString().replace('|',',').split(',');
```

o Código acima está usando 3 funções do jQuery.

- `toString()` - converte a array em string e separa as posições do array por "virgula"
  *Exemplo : 'Escova|Corte,Masculino,Gel,Cabelo|Corte Masculino'*
- `.replace('|',',')` - esta função como o nome já diz Substitui um valor pelo o outro, ou seja,  o primeiro parâmetro pelo segundo. 
  Neste caso o **"|"** por **","**
- `.split(',')` - e por ultimo a função SPLIT divide a String a partir do parâmetro passado, que por sua vez é **","**.

No fim o passo a passo é :

- Pega a array e converte em string (separando as posições com virgula)
- Substitui os | (pipes) por virgula.
- Converta novamente a string em Array dividindo-a toda vez que encontrar uma virgula.

> O grande problema dessa solução é que ele aplica o replace apenas na primeira ocorrência que encontrar, ou seja, se a array conter mais de um elemento com o | ele apenas substituirá o primeiro. (chato né?)

Mas relaxa, que ai quem vem a expressão regular para ajudar.

```
.replace(/\|/g,',')
```

O uso da expressão regular, faz com que o replace substitua todas as ocorrências do carácter pipe (**|**) dentro da string.

Caso não tenha familiriadade com o expressão regular, segue um bom material para estudo:
[Quero aprender](https://tableless.com.br/o-basico-sobre-expressoes-regulares/)

Enfim, o resultado final do método é :

```
var teste = ['Escova|Corte Masculino','Gel','Cabelo|Barba']; // Array com os dados
teste = teste.toString().replace(/\|/g,',').split(',');
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Ajudou bastante @Abner Simões! Muito obrigado pela contribuição e ajuda ao meu aprendizado! =]

Comment: Que bom @André Albson, Sucesso cara.